# non-greedy grep

Tags: grep

I want to grep a link from an external file `example.txt`.

`example.txt` containins:

```
(https://example.com/pathto/music.mp3)music.mp3
```

the code:

```
egrep -o -m1 '(https)[^'\"]+.mp3' example.txt
```

output:

```
https://example.com/pathto/music1.mp3)music.mp3
```

When I run grep, it detect the last .mp3 as end of output while I just need it end after first occurrence. How can I tell grep to stop after finding the first pattern?

My desired output:

```
https://example.com/pathto/music.mp3
```

I just want to extract any string starting with `https` and ending with `mp3`

Comment: the + operator in grep is greedfy; you want a non-greedy match...

Comment: no, I dont care about `(`and `)`. I just want to extract any string starting with `https` and ending with `mp3`

Comment: in my data after the links there are name of the files.it is not immediately after but it is somewhere in text.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I read the documentation. but i didn't understand what is non-greedy version of `+` . For instance `?+` or `{1}` also result in the same. Can you please tell me what is the non-greedy equivalent of `+` ? http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?grep_regular_expressions.html

Comment: I read your regexp a little too quickly; your [] is telling grep to grab everything that's not a single- or double-quote. Does a ) always end your desired filename? `[^)]` would work in that case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standard grep does not accept the `?` modifier that would normally make it non-greedy.

But you can try the -P option that - if enabled in your distro - will make it accept Perl style regexes:

```
grep -oP -m1 "(https)[^'\"]+?.mp3" mp3.txt
```

If that does not work, you could for your specific example include the right parenthesis in the range so it wouldn't look beyond the parenthesis:

```
egrep -o -m1 "(https)[^'\")]+?.mp3" mp3.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

egrep does not support non-greedy matching. Using perl mode `-P` will help you:

```
grep -o -m1 -P  'https.*?mp3' example.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
~$ cat example.txt
(https://example.com/pathto/music.mp3)music.mp3

~$ grep -Po "(https)[^'\"].*?mp3" example.txt
https://example.com/pathto/music.mp3
```